# Prove that the sine of a complex conjugate is equal to the conjugate of the sine of the complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove that given $z\in \mathbb{C}$ it follows that:

$\sin(\bar z)= \overline{\sin(z)}$

I don't know how to start the proof, so any advice can be useful. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin(z)$?

Comment: That's all information I have, but:

$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ where $z=x+iy,$ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

You can use the Taylor expansion of  $$\sin(z)= z-z^3/3!+ z^5/5!+\dots$$

Also use the property of conjugate that $$\overline{z_1 + z_2}=\overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}$$

$$\overline{z_1 \times z_2}=\overline{z_1} \times \overline{z_2}$$